# Raspberry Pi 4B crashing before properly booting

Tags: pi-4, boot-issues

I'm sorry if this question has already been asked but I've been looking for a while and I can't find anything that's really helped.

I recently got a Raspberry Pi 4b but when I connect it to a screen,

- Green and red lights flash initially and I start to see it boot up but (with a one time exception) it crashes before it has finished booting and the green light stops flashing.
- Before it crashes it shows a rainbow screen then shows 4 of the raspberry pi symbols in the top left and sometimes starts to have the text below it before it crashes.
- When I boot it without an SSD, the red light is on and the green light flashes 4 times on a loop.
- I've tried everything I can find but this seems to be buried under the SPI EEPROM problem and I can't seem to find anyone else who has quite the same problem.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

- I have since tried it with the official raspberry pi power supply and still have the same issue.
- I have also read through the pi4b post in the sticky and none of those issues seem to be the case (I do get the 4 flashes with no ssd so it's not the EEPROM issue, I have been using blank versions or raspbian on both a 16GB and a 32GB ssd, The green light gradually stops flashing and does not flash regularly.
- I only have the power and microHDMI plugged in (I've tried 2 separate cords for both)).

Comment: Try creating a new SDCard with plain Raspbian or plain Raspbian Lite and booting that. If it boots run `sudo apt update; sudo apt dist-upgrade -y; sudo reboot` to pull in the latest fixes and latest EEPROM code. The go back to the original SDCard and see if you can work out why it doesn't boot normally.

Comment: I can try the upgrade if it boots again but I've just been trying to boot it for the first time so the software is all plain.

Comment: Please have a look at [The Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151).

Answer (score 0):

The most common issue with the Pi 4 and booting is an inadequate power supply.  What PS are you using and what is its output capacity.

The best results are with a genuine Raspberry Pi 4 supply with the USB-C output.  Most other supplies do not provide enough output current to make the 4 work properly.

Comment: I'm using a SABRENT fast charging usb hub that claims to output 5V and 3A max. I also ordered a genuine supply but it hasn't arrived yet and I've not got high hopes on reliable shipping any time soon and based on the specs of this it SHOULD work right?